# Node json2xls downloadable file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json2xls

I have the following (simple) node module:

```
var json2xls = require('json2xls');
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function (router, mongoose) {
    router.route('/client/toExcel')
        .post(function (req, res) {
            var obj = req.body.data;
            var xls = json2xls(obj);

            fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
            res.download('data.xlsx');

        });
    return router;
};
```

Now when i call this from my frontend. The node server creates the file however it sends back the file but as text and not as a downloadable file here is a screenshot at my console:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Here is a image of my request:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried telling express the filename manually like so

```
res.download('/data.xlsx', 'data.xlsx');
```

I've had success with that before now.

Comment: How do I download in client-side(browser) without writing the file in the server?

Comment: It's not working. I am getting the below error in excel.
Removed Part: /xl/sharedStrings.xml part with XML error.  (Strings) Illegal xml character. Line 1, column 153.
Removed Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet.xml part

Comment: that's a problem with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly download your file by just calling your API

```
var json2xls = require('json2xls');
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function (router, mongenter code hereoose) {
    router.route('/client/toExcel')
        .post(function (req, res) {
            var obj = req.body.data;

            res.xls('data.xlsx', obj);
        });
    return router;
};
```